# What is the fontawesome default font em size?

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-size

I want know the best size of illustrator artboard for design font awesome icon.

What is the default font `em` size in font awesome?

[The tutorial](http://asimpleframe.com/writing/custom-icon-font-tutorial-icomoon#fn:3)  said:

> "First, create a new artboard with a size of 512px × 512px (IcoMoon App’s default font em size). Next, set the document grid to represent pixels."

But I don't know font awesome default font `em` size.

Answer (score 1):

This is the fontawesome class:

```
.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

So, to answer your question, it is 14px or 1em.

Answer (score 1):

The default size is **1 em**

Font awesome also has 5 default classes for larger icons:

```
fa-lg: 1.33333 em
fa-2x: 2em
fa-3x: 3em
fa-4x: 4em
fa-5x: 5em
```

Comment: Yes, The default size is 14px. Then 14*28(like tutorial) is the best size of illust artboard?